# SQL ORACLE 'UNION' AND 'WHERE' ISSUE / QUESTION

Tags: oracle

I've wanted to compare the diffrence between UNION and WHERE in SQL / ORACLE

I've created two test queries but they both gave me diffrent results

Using Union

```
SELECT prod_id, ilosc
FROM ElementyZamowienia
WHERE ilosc = 100
UNION
SELECT prod_id, ilosc
FROM ElementyZamowienia
WHERE prod_id LIKE '%BNBG';
```

Output:

```
BR01        100
BR03        100
BNBG01      100
BNBG02      100
BNBG03      100
```

And Using  WHERE

```
SELECT prod_id, ilosc
FROM ElementyZamowienia
WHERE ilosc = 100 AND prod_id LIKE 'BNBG%';
```

Output:

```
BNBG01      100
BNBG02      100
BNBG03      100
```

The output made with WHERE is the correct one. Any idea why there is such a diffrence bettwen those queries?

Comment: UNION is essentially giving you an OR, when you want AND.

Comment: Thank u @KenShirriff

Comment: [Set Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF): *`UNION
All` - distinct rows selected by **either** query*. Did you read what union does?

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```sql
SELECT prod_id, ilosc
FROM   ElementyZamowienia
WHERE  ilosc = 100
UNION
SELECT prod_id, ilosc
FROM   ElementyZamowienia
WHERE  prod_id LIKE 'BNBG%';
```

Is the same as using `OR` (rather than `AND`):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       prod_id,
       ilosc
FROM   ElementyZamowienia
WHERE  ilosc = 100
OR     prod_id LIKE 'BNBG%';
```

*Note: If you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` then you would not get rid of duplicates and would not need `DISTINCT`.*